# How long is the cropped region when adjust images for iPhone X?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to adjust images in my app for iPhoneX with using aspectFill.
Now the background image of the app looks like the bellow image "Cropping on iPhone X". But I don't know how long is the cropped religion (width), that is red colored on the image.

Does anyone know that?

[image: cropped image]

Comment: It's base on your image size, the 4.7'' device has screen size `750px × 1334px` and iPhone X has screen size `1125px × 2436px`

Comment: ohh I see! Then the width in red region is 1125 - 750 = 375, right? It's quite silly question...

Comment: don't forget the ratio between your image size and screen size